# Older Ruby Version Showing After Installing Latest One | rbenv and zsh

Tags: ruby, installation, zsh, rbenv

I need some assistance with installing rbenv and Ruby 2.6.6. I'm currently using zsh, I want to install Ruby 2.6.6, so I did the following:

```
brew install rbenv
rbenv install 2.6.6
rbenv global 2.6.6
```

After I did this, I restarted the terminal and I performed the following statement to check the ruby version:

```
ruby -v
```

However, the ruby version states:

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

I've tried restarting my terminal and repeated the same steps. I'm new to programming, just need your assistance in helping me fix my setup issues.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Did you try to run the [`rbenv-doctor` script](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos) (step 4 in the install docs)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is picking up your system Ruby, not the `rbenv` installed one. You can confirm that with `which ruby`, which should not say `/usr/bin/ruby` but something like `/Users/<your account/.rbenv/bin` (or similar, I don't use `rbenv` myself anymore). You need to configure your `$PATH` to make sure this comes before `/usr/bin`.

The command `rbenv init` should have taken care of this. If you didn't run it, do that. You can also perform the necessary steps manually, see the [documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell) for that.